# Sending a track across cameras

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-tracking

There are two cameras looking at opposite sides. I have two videos sync recorded from them. I have to track persons assigning them a unique ID(done(for the single video)). The problem is when a person goes from [first camera's area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1m31.png)(red square is where person appears/disappears) to the [second's one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9nvl.png)(red square is where person appears/disappears) I must somehow predict coordinates of where person may appear in the second area or backwards and feed them(including ID) to the tracker.

P.S There is also a person who starts walking from a blind spot(between cameras).
Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from numpy.lib.type_check import imag
import math

minimum = 6000             
frame1 = None
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/timur/Downloads/2.mp4")
#cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/timur/Downloads/2.mp4")

method = 'ABS'

mog = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()  
knn = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()



distances = []
detectedCount = 0
cpoints_prev_frame = []
tracking_objects = {}
track_id = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    vid = cv2.flip(frame,1)
    vid = frame

    #ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()
    #vid2 = frame2

    #triggerArea = 191 628 980 717
    triggerArea = frame[630:690,191:980]
    #triggerArea2 = frame2[630:690,191:980]

    if not ret:
        print("END")
        break

    cpoints_cur_frame = []

    curPerson = None
    
    if method == 'MOG2':
        bgs = mog.apply(vid)
        
    
    elif method == 'KNN':
        bgs = knn.apply(vid)
    
    elif method == 'ABS':
        frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(vid,(7,7),0)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        if frame1 is None:
            frame1 = frame
            continue 
        
        framedelta = cv2.absdiff(frame1,frame)
        retval, bgs = cv2.threshold(framedelta.copy(), 35, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    mask = np.zeros_like(frame)

    
    contours,_ = cv2.findContours(bgs, mode= cv2.RETR_TREE, method= cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse= True)
    
    for cnt in contours:
        detectedCount += 1
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < minimum:
                continue
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cx = int((x + x + w) / 2)
        cy = int((y + y + h) / 2)
        cpoints_cur_frame.append((cx, cy))
        cv2.rectangle(vid,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,10),1)
        cv2.putText(vid,f'{method}',(20,20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1,(0,255,0,2))
        cv2.putText(vid,'Timurchik',(20,40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1,(0,255,0,2))
        cv2.drawContours(mask,cnt,-1,255,3)
        break



    if detectedCount <= 2:
        for pt in cpoints_cur_frame:
            for pt2 in cpoints_prev_frame:
                distance = math.hypot(pt2[0] - pt[0], pt2[1] - pt[1])

                if distance < 130:
                    tracking_objects[track_id] = pt
                    track_id += 1

    else:

        tracking_objects_copy = tracking_objects.copy()
        center_points_cur_frame_copy = cpoints_cur_frame.copy()

        for object_id, pt2 in tracking_objects_copy.items():
            object_exists = False
            for pt in center_points_cur_frame_copy:
                distance = math.hypot(pt2[0] - pt[0], pt2[1] - pt[1])
                distances.append(distance)
                print(max(distances))
                if distance < 110:
                    tracking_objects[object_id] = pt
                    object_exists = True
                    if pt in cpoints_cur_frame:
                        cpoints_cur_frame.remove(pt)
                    continue

            if not object_exists:
                tracking_objects.pop(object_id)

        for pt in cpoints_cur_frame:
            tracking_objects[track_id] = pt
            track_id += 1

    for object_id, pt in tracking_objects.items():
        cv2.circle(vid, pt, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(vid, str(object_id), (pt[0], pt[1] - 7), 0, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)



    cv2.imshow('triggerArea', triggerArea)
    #cv2.imshow('triggerArea2', triggerArea2)
    cv2.imshow('frame',vid)
    #cv2.imshow('BGS',bgs)


    cpoints_prev_frame = cpoints_cur_frame.copy()

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q') or key == ord('Q'):
        break
    elif key == ord('M') or key == ord('m'):
        method = 'MOG2'
    elif key == ord('K') or key == ord('k'):
        method = 'KNN'
    elif key == ord('A') or key == ord('a'):
        method = 'ABS'

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: could you include your code in your post so we can get a bteer understanding of what you have already done?

Comment: video data would be even more useful. -- given those pictures, just use your intuition and wing it: anything leaving A at coordinate `x` will enter B at coordinate `w-x`. it's gonna be good enough and nothing more complicated will be much better. for the "tracking by association", you could also give your people some identifying attributes... perhaps apply some flavor of "person re-id" network and forget about engineering this manually.

Comment: sorry for being late with updating with code

Comment: reid is too far for me. Im a beginning guy so im not allowed even use DeepSORT